# Understanding type casting of + operator in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date object in moment

```
const myDate = moment.utc(new Date()).startOf('day');
```

Approach # 1

```
console.log(myDate.valueOf());
```

vs Approach # 2

```
console.log(+myDate());
```

Both of these do the same thing, I want to know how this `+myDate()` operates & I couldn't find the documentation for this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a momentjs thing, it's how the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator works in JavaScript.

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already.
>   Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus
>   is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a
>   number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find the documentation for this anywhere.

It's [in the JavaScript specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator). :-)

The unary `+` operator converts its operand to number via the abstract [`ToNumber`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) operation, which (for objects) calls `valueOf` (then if necessary because that returns an object[!], calls `toString`) and converts the resulting primitive to a number if it isn't already one.

Since the moment object supports `valueOf` and it returns a number, `+myDate` and `myDate.valueOf()` do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't actually knew the exact term of what I had to search. Now I know thanks a bunch sir.